# Use Powershell to upload to Bitbucket Downloads section

Tags: powershell, curl, file-upload, bitbucket

So we switched to Bitbucket recently - Love the different pricing model / the branch and repo permissions. But, I REALLY miss the Releases feature in GitHub.

BB does however have a "Downloads" section that we can upload recent binaries to. But... It isnt exposed via their API.

I found a nifty script that uses cURL, but I wanted to do this in PowerShell so I dont need any special programs (we use AppVeyor as our CI Server, no cURL).

I have this mostly working - The process is:

1. Load Signin page to get CSRF token - working
2. Sign in, redirecting to downloads page - working
3. Upload file - failing

My code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/wjdavis5/bitbucket-curl-upload-to-repo-downloads/src/55992be86e16ae86817879655079ceccd759fa4c/upload-to-bitbucket.ps1?at=PowerShell)

I have isolated the problem to the form data. Here is what it looks like in fiddler when I just do the upload myself:
[image: Fiddler snip manual upload]

But when I use Powershell I cannot get it to populate the "WebForms" tab of the request. I've tried using the -InFile and specifying the file to upload, but Bitbucket requires the other shown parameters as well.

How do I specify a series of "Form Fields" to include in the request with Powershell?

**EDIT**
Adding code here, even though it makes this messy.

```
$baseUri = "https://bitbucket.org"
$teamName = "xxxxxxxxx"
$projectName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$page = "/$teamName/$projectName/downloads"
$uri = "https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/"
$username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$headers = @{
  "referer" = "$uri"
}
$json = @"
{
    "username":"$username",
    "password":"$password",
    "submit":"",
    "next":"$page",
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken":""
 }
"@

$formData = @"
{
    "token":"",
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken":""
 }
"@

$body = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$formData2 = $formData | ConvertFrom-Json

#Load the page once to get the csrf token
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -SessionVariable mySession -Method Get -OutFile test2.html

#Parse the token
$body.csrfmiddlewaretoken = $mySession.Cookies.GetCookies("https://bitbucket.org")[0].Value
$formData2.csrfmiddlewaretoken = $mySession.Cookies.GetCookies("https://bitbucket.org")[0].Value
#Load the token into the object
$json = $body | ConvertTo-Json
$formData = $formData2 | ConvertTo-Json

#build the uri data needed by bb
$uriData = "username=" + $body.username + "&password=" + $body.password + "&submit=&next=" + $body.next + "&csrfmiddlewaretoken=" + $body.csrfmiddlewaretoken

#Sign into BB now
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/" -WebSession $mySession -Body $uriData -Method Post -OutFile test.html -Headers $headers

#Update referer to the downloads page
$headers.referer = $baseuri + $page
$fulluri = $baseuri + $page

#Upload the file
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$fulluri" -Method Post -OutFile test3.html -WebSession $mySession -Headers $headers -Body $formData -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Can you not post the code in the question?

Comment: @arco444 yeah sure- updated the question with the code

Comment: Hard to know what's going on without seeing the request trace - but it's unusual to do a POST to *download* a file

Comment: @arco444 I'm not posting to download a file. I'm trying to upload a file to the "Downloads" section of Bitbucket's website. I have this working with a curl script I found so rewriting it into PS is currently on hold..